# htaccess Rewrite with exceptions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm developing a new website on a server that uses `~` for user directories. So the new site (old one is still online while developing) is hosted under **domain.com/~cms/**. Is that a problem? I never saw that before ... *I know its not from outerspace but ... kind of uncommon isn't it?*

I need to know if there is a proper solution via .htacces Redirect to rewrite all requests to that subdirectory BUT leave some old URIs like **domain.com/dir1** or **domain.com/dir2** untouched ...

Is that possible? I know some basic .htaccess stuff but since the live page is still up I dont want to fool around on this server without beeing sure :)

Thx!!